# Unity how change the intractable property with the code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i have 3d Sphere and i would like to change the interactable property by code, but i have an error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** when i try to set the boolean value.
Please note that the script is attached to the 3d Object

this is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Drag : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button obj;

    void Awake()
    {
        Button obj = GameObject.Find("Sphere").GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
       this.obj.interactable = false;

    } 
}
```

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is this object called “Sphere” you don’t show a component called Button on it. Either would result in that error.

Comment: @BugFinder, the GameObject sphere seems doesn't have the property interactable.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post i've understood that you want to disable **Interactable Component**

```
public Interactable interactable;

void Awake()
{
    interactable = GetComponent<Interactable>();
}

void Start()
{
   interactable.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: super thank you!